# Need help in removing the "," after "and" in a user created list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program for a class and the instructions are to use the first part of the code that the instructor gave us which is:

```
pc_parts = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        pc_parts.append(newWord)
```

He wants us to add our own portion of code in that will display all of the items that the user inputs, separated by a comma, with "and" between the last two items. But the code I am using keeps inserting a comma after and. I need help if getting rid of that last comma. The portion of code I wrote is:

```
if len(pc_parts) > 1:
    pc_parts.insert(-1, 'and')
print(*pc_parts, sep=', ')`
```

And the output if I type in "motherboard", "processor", "graphics card", "hard drive" is:

"motherboard, processor, graphics card, and, hard drive"

I need the comma after "and" gone. HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some list, for example:

```
someList = ["motherboard", "processor", "graphics card", "hard drive"]
```

Then you can first print out all but the last element like so:

```
print(*someList[0:len(someList) - 1], sep = ", ", end = ", and ")
```

The first part of the above code prints from index 0 to the last element of the list. This is denoted by [0:len(someList) - 1].

We also decide that each element will be separated by ", ". I.e. a comma and a space. This is done with the parameter sep=", ".

We then designate the string to print ", and " after all elements specified have been printed. At this point the screen will read:

```
motherboard, processor, graphics card, and
```

Then we print out the last element with the following line:

```
print(someList[len(someList) - 1])
```

At this point the console will read:

```
motherboard, processor, graphics card, and hard drive
```

All together the code looks like:

```
someList = ["motherboard", "processor", "graphics card", "hard drive"] 
print(*someList[0:len(someList) - 1], sep = ", ", end = ", and ")
print(someList[len(someList) - 1])
```

Try checking out the python documentation for print() too, it may seem overwhelming but try to read what the function does line by line :)

Here it is:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Or an easier to understand link:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I just needed the last two print() functions you provided and it worked. I can type anything, in any order, and it outputs correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyDelMonte Be sure to understand each and every character of the code!!! It will make the rest of your class much easier. There's no worse torture than not understanding your own code. Good luck!

Comment: I do understand it completely. I am kicking myself for not being able to figure it out. Once I saw your code, I thought "Duh!" to myself lol. Its a simple fix, I was just overthinking it.